# Can the algorithm be optimized?

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion, backtracking, coin-change, memoization

I am new to backtracking and recursion. I have seen numerous explanations on how on to find the minimum number of coins needed to make a particular amount. This involves a top down dynamic approach with mermoization and a bottom up using dynamic programming. Even the brute force apporach always starts using a top down approach breaking the problem down into smaller sub problems and then caching.

However, I have written the following algorithm that is not optimized to do the same but cannot figure out how to apply memoization. Is it even possible?

My basic algorithm is I start from sum = 0 and keep count of how many coins I have used by adding coin values and then returning the minimum count.

```
//function is called with sum = 0, coins = 0 and minCoins = Integer.MAX_VALUE
//coins[] contains the different coin denominations and target is the desired amount
// count is the number of coins that have been used

public static int makeChangeBacktracking(int sum, int[] coins, int target, int count, int minCoins) {

        if(sum == target) {
            return count;
        }

        for(int coin : coins) {
            //choose
            sum+= coin;
            //explore
            if(sum <= target) { //if it is greater than the target then why recurse???
                int c = makeChangeBacktracking(sum, coins, target, count + 1, minCoins);
                if(minCoins > c) {
                    minCoins = c;
                }
                //undo  
                sum-= coin;
            }
        }
        return minCoins;
    }
```

I would like to apply any technique to improve the run time of the above algorithm. A clear explanation of whether or not memoization or other optimization techniques can be applied to this to speed up would be helpful.

Comment: This problem is known as the Change-making Problem. See the related wikipage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem .

Comment: Thanks but the link doesn't explain going from sum 0 and then picking coins and any optimization for it. Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: Currently the fastest solutions to the unbounded change-making problem are branch-and-bound algorithms with additional optimizations (such as partial/full memoization).  See here for one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45121962/109122

Answer (score -2):

A simple and efficient algorithm would be (correct me if I'm wrong):

1) Find the biggest valued coin just below that particular amount
2) Do the same thing with amount - coin_chosen
3) Repeat until convergence

Does this solve your problem?

e.g   Available coins: 1p,2p,5p,10p,20p,50p,£1 ...
47p -> -20p -> 27p -> -20p -> 17p -> -10p -> 7p -> -5p -> 2p -> -2p -> 0p

There are other less efficient ways to do this like maybe using genetic algorithms but I guess this would be the quickest ...

Comment: This is a greedy algorithm where its correctness depends on the available coins. Consider the coin set $\{1,4,9\}$ and the target sum of 12. By your approach, we need 4 coins: one 9, three times 1. The optimal number is 3 coins.

Comment: thanks but that is a greedy approach and the brute force will not give the true minimum number of coins.

Comment: What do you mean with "and the brute force will not give the true minimum number of coins"?

Comment: @STanja This approach works for the standard coin system 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,etc. As most of the coins are multiples of 5 and 1,2,5 are "basically primes". But if there were an algorithm for any set of coins I'm all ears. However, I guess this is a semi NP problem. You could also use genetic algorithms ...

Comment: Anyway STanja how would you get the number 3 with your set of coins?

Comment: @STanja, all i meant was a greedy approach doesnt always give an optimal solution. Also there is something off with your example. Not sure the right coins are 3.

Comment: @Spindoctor yes it's 3. 4*3 ...

Comment: touche...thanks david.....any idea on how to go from a sum 0 and optimize?

Comment: What do you mean with sum 0?

Comment: if I start of with amount 0 and work my way up using recursion and backtracking pick each coin and exploring?

Comment: Take a look at the website STanja mentioned before:  [link] en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem[/link]. I think you will find it very useful!